# Нарисовать изображение на весь Canvas

Tags: javascript, dom

Я работаю с загрузкой фотографий, пытаюсь отображать миниатюры этих фото. Для изменения размера фотографий использую `canvas`. Проблема в том, что `canvas` рисует фотографии меньшего размера, хотя для фотографии я задаю размеры такие-же как и сам `canvas`.
Проблема, как мне кажется, кроется в самой отрисовке `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);`, но не знаю как это победить.

---

Цель данных телодвижений - облегчить работу браузеру, так как пользователи(Они же тетки) будут грузить фотки прямо с фотика, тоесть ситуация, когда отображается штук 500 фоток размером 5к пикселей - обычное дело.

```js
//Готовим шаблон
let template = document.getElementById('file-template');
let cTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template.innerHTML);

let input = document.getElementById('file-input');

input.onchange = function() {
  let container = document.getElementById('photos');
  let files = this.files;
  
  //Перебираем файлы в мультиинпуте
  for(let i in files) {
    if(!files.hasOwnProperty(i))
      continue;
  
    let file = files[i]; 

    if (!file.type.match(/image.*/))
      continue;

    let reader = new FileReader();

    //Когда картинка прочиталась
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = e.target.result;

      //Вставляем из шаблона
      container.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', cTemplate() );  
      
      let canvas = container.querySelector('.file:last-of-type .canvas');
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      let height = 100;   //Высота превьюх 100
      let width = img.width * height / img.height; //Посчитаем их длину

      canvas.style['width'] = width + 'px';   //Канвас хотим длиной с картинку
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);  //Тут почему-то неправильно отрабатывает
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};
```

```css
#photos {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.file {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.file-delete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 18px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
canvas {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple">
<div id="photos"></div>

<script id="file-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="file">
  <a href='#' class="file-delete">&times;</a>
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Готовим шаблон
let template = document.getElementById('file-template');
let cTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template.innerHTML);

let input = document.getElementById('file-input');

input.onchange = function() {
  let container = document.getElementById('photos');
  let files = this.files;

  //Перебираем файлы в мультиинпуте
  for (let i in files) {
    if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i))
      continue;

    let file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.match(/image.*/))
      continue;

    let reader = new FileReader();

    //Когда картинка прочиталась
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = e.target.result;

      //Вставляем из шаблона
      container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cTemplate());

      let canvas = container.querySelector('.file:last-of-type').querySelector('.canvas');
      canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      canvas.style['width'] = img.naturalWidth / 4 + 'px';
      canvas.style['height'] = img.naturalHeight / 4 + 'px';
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};
```

```css
#photos {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.file {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.file-delete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 18px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
canvas {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple">
<div id="photos"></div>

<script id="file-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="file">
    <a href='#' class="file-delete">&times;</a>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше внимание, у меня вопрос. Сделать огромные канвасы и потом пожать их в 4 раза - не одно и то же, что сделать большие картинки и пожать их в верске? Сейчас чуть подправлю вопрос, напишу свою цель, чтоб было понятнее что меня беспокоит

Comment: @user200141 вы хотите ужать размеры картинок?

Comment: Уточнил вопрос. Я пытаюсь не загнуть браузер на слабеньких офисных компах, отображая превьюхи

Comment: @user200141 я думаю, что для начала ограничить кол-во картинок для загрузки...?)

Comment: Мне кажется это не очень удобно для пользователя

Comment: Присвоение `canvas.width` и `canvas.height` (Не через `.style`) вычисленных длины и высоты решило мою проблему. Вы мне помогли!

Comment: @user200141 я рад. удачи!)